# firebird update very slow

Tags: performance, transaction, firebird

I am writing a stored procedure for Firebird 2.5 in which I sometimes need to update a single row in a data table more than once in the same transaction. However, I have noticed that the performance degrades drastically when I do this. (From an execution time measure in ms to sometimes a second or more!)
Is this something intrinsic to Firebird 2.5, or am I mistaken? 
Do I just need to ensure that I only update each row once per transaction?

Comment: I didn't notice any of this, while doing 100 updates of the same record just now. In one transaction, 200K row table - nothing took more than 0.03 secs. Naturally it depends on table (column count, number of indexed columns, constraints, maybe db buffers). There could be many reasons why you're seeing this.